# history.push redirects to requested url but does not render related component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have below routing in app function:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={ListOfItems}></Route>
<Route path="/list/:searchquery?" component={ListOfItems}></Route>
```

second Route is working well when i pass any search term but when i try to access first route '/' using history.push('/') calling by function it changes the url in the browser but does not render the component of '/' route.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
const history = createBrowserHistory();

const redirectToHome = () => {
    history.push('/');
}
```

could you please suggest me what is the issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this a typo `<Route exact path="/" component={ListOfItems}></Route>` you are passing the same component as in your `path="/list/:searchquery?"`?

Comment: @NemanjaLazarevic - Thanks for your reply, No i want to show listofitems component on home page also on search result page.

Comment: Does refreshing a page on `/` works as expected?